# Submit Button On React Form Doesnt Run Submit Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a login form using react, however when pressing the submit button nothing occurs in the console

```
   import React from "react";




export class Login extends React.Component {


    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.submitHandler = this.submitHandler.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
        }
    }
    changeHandler = (e) => {
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }
    submitHandler = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log("worked")
        console.log(this.state)
    }

    render() {
        const {username, password} = this.state

        return <div className = "base-container" ref={this.props.containerRef}>
            <div className="content">
              <div className="logo">
                <img src={Logo} alt="logo"/>
              </div>
              <div className="form" onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                  <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="username"> Username</label>
                      <input type="text" 
                      name="username" 
                      value ={username} 
                      placeholder="Username"
                      onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="password"> Password</label>
                      <input type="password" 
                      name="password" 
                      value={password} 
                      placeholder="Password"
                      onChange ={this.changeHandler}/>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="footer">
                <button type="submit" className="btn">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    }
}
```

is there something that I am missing? I have tried moving the submit button into the form tags but that doesnt seem to work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a form tag for `onSubmit` to work. Also, if you want to `preventDefault`, you need to pass in the event in the `submitHandler`.

So replace:

```
<div className="form" onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
```

With:

```
<form className="form" onSubmit={this.submitHandler(event)}>
```

Also make sure you replace the closing `</div>` with `</form>`

Comment: :-)  No problem!

Answer (score 0):

The onSubmit property is specific for forms not divs. You can either change the div to a form or change change the onSubmit to an onClick, and put the onClick to the button. Also, if you are defining class methods with arrow function, you do not need to bind it to this in the constructor. Hope that helps!

Edit: If using the form, the submit button must be inside the form's closing tag.